# Custom Masked Passwordbox in WPF

Tags: wpf, passwords

In iOS when you are typing a password into a field the last letter of the field is displayed but then is obfuscated when you type the next character. Is there a way to duplicate this behavior in WPF?

Comment: This is considered bad practice if you're doing this on a desktop app. Consider the fact that on a phone people watching over your shoulder is much less to a large monitor on a desktop. So unless you intend for this on Windows phone or tablet. Think again.

Comment: @Viv makes sense, but unfortunately, I am not dictating requirements in this scenario.

Comment: @Viv plus, this application may be used by people that could tend toward the visually impaired side, might make a little more sense in that situation.

Comment: It can be done with an Attached Property per http://wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html but I doubt I good IT security officer would let it deploy

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your usage for such a thing in a desktop app is justified, then you can do something like the following.

We had a similar requirement before and this is what I did.

- I created a custom `Passwordbox` by deriving from `TextBox` and adding a new DP of type `SecureString` to it (pretty much the same concept as a normal `PasswordBox`). We do not lose any security benefits this way and can customize the visual behavior to our heart's content.
- With this now we can use the `Text` of the `TextBox` as it's display-string and hold the actual password in the back-end `SecureString` DP and bind it to the VM.
- We handle the `PreviewTextInput` and `PreviewKeyDown` events to manage all text changes in the control, including stuff like `Key.Back`, `Key.Delete` and the annoying `Key.Space`(which does not come through the `PreviewTextInput`

**iOS Feel:**

Couple more things to note for an exact iOS behavior.

1. Last character is only shown while adding new characters to the "end of the current string" (`FlowDirection` independent)
2. Editing characters in-between an existing string has no effect on mask.
3. Last character shown is timer-dependent (becomes an "*" after a certain period if left idle)
4. All copy-paste operations disabled in the control.

First 2 points can be handled pretty easily when detecting text changes, for the last one we can use a `DispatcherTimer` to work with the display-string accordingly.

So putting this all together we end up with:

```
/// <summary>
///   This class contains properties for CustomPasswordBox
/// </summary>
internal class CustomPasswordBox : TextBox {
  #region Member Variables
  /// <summary>
  ///   Dependency property to hold watermark for CustomPasswordBox
  /// </summary>
  public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Password", typeof(SecureString), typeof(CustomPasswordBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(new SecureString()));

  /// <summary>
  ///   Private member holding mask visibile timer
  /// </summary>
  private readonly DispatcherTimer _maskTimer;
  #endregion

  #region Constructors
  /// <summary>
  ///   Initialises a new instance of the LifeStuffPasswordBox class.
  /// </summary>
  public CustomPasswordBox() {
    PreviewTextInput += OnPreviewTextInput;
    PreviewKeyDown += OnPreviewKeyDown;
    CommandManager.AddPreviewExecutedHandler(this, PreviewExecutedHandler);
    _maskTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1) };
    _maskTimer.Tick += (sender, args) => MaskAllDisplayText();
  }
  #endregion

  #region Commands & Properties
  /// <summary>
  ///   Gets or sets dependency Property implementation for Password
  /// </summary>
  public SecureString Password {
    get {
      return (SecureString)GetValue(PasswordProperty);
    }

    set {
      SetValue(PasswordProperty, value);
    }
  }
  #endregion

  #region Methods
  /// <summary>
  ///   Method to handle PreviewExecutedHandler events
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="sender">Sender object</param>
  /// <param name="executedRoutedEventArgs">Event Text Arguments</param>
  private static void PreviewExecutedHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs executedRoutedEventArgs) {
    if (executedRoutedEventArgs.Command == ApplicationCommands.Copy ||
        executedRoutedEventArgs.Command == ApplicationCommands.Cut ||
        executedRoutedEventArgs.Command == ApplicationCommands.Paste) {
      executedRoutedEventArgs.Handled = true;
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  ///   Method to handle PreviewTextInput events
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="sender">Sender object</param>
  /// <param name="textCompositionEventArgs">Event Text Arguments</param>
  private void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs textCompositionEventArgs) {
    AddToSecureString(textCompositionEventArgs.Text);
    textCompositionEventArgs.Handled = true;
  }

  /// <summary>
  ///   Method to handle PreviewKeyDown events
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="sender">Sender object</param>
  /// <param name="keyEventArgs">Event Text Arguments</param>
  private void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs) {
    Key pressedKey = keyEventArgs.Key == Key.System ? keyEventArgs.SystemKey : keyEventArgs.Key;
    switch (pressedKey) {
      case Key.Space:
        AddToSecureString(" ");
        keyEventArgs.Handled = true;
        break;
      case Key.Back:
      case Key.Delete:
        if (SelectionLength > 0) {
          RemoveFromSecureString(SelectionStart, SelectionLength);
        } else if (pressedKey == Key.Delete && CaretIndex < Text.Length) {
          RemoveFromSecureString(CaretIndex, 1);
        } else if (pressedKey == Key.Back && CaretIndex > 0) {
          int caretIndex = CaretIndex;
          if (CaretIndex > 0 && CaretIndex < Text.Length)
            caretIndex = caretIndex - 1;
          RemoveFromSecureString(CaretIndex - 1, 1);
          CaretIndex = caretIndex;
        }

        keyEventArgs.Handled = true;
        break;
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  ///   Method to add new text into SecureString and process visual output
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="text">Text to be added</param>
  private void AddToSecureString(string text) {
    if (SelectionLength > 0) {
      RemoveFromSecureString(SelectionStart, SelectionLength);
    }

    foreach (char c in text) {
      int caretIndex = CaretIndex;
      Password.InsertAt(caretIndex, c);
      MaskAllDisplayText();
      if (caretIndex == Text.Length) {
        _maskTimer.Stop();
        _maskTimer.Start();
        Text = Text.Insert(caretIndex++, c.ToString());
      } else {
        Text = Text.Insert(caretIndex++, "*");
      }
      CaretIndex = caretIndex;
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  ///   Method to remove text from SecureString and process visual output
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="startIndex">Start Position for Remove</param>
  /// <param name="trimLength">Length of Text to be removed</param>
  private void RemoveFromSecureString(int startIndex, int trimLength) {
    int caretIndex = CaretIndex;
    for (int i = 0; i < trimLength; ++i) {
      Password.RemoveAt(startIndex);
    }

    Text = Text.Remove(startIndex, trimLength);
    CaretIndex = caretIndex;
  }

  private void MaskAllDisplayText() {
    _maskTimer.Stop();
    int caretIndex = CaretIndex;
    Text = new string('*', Text.Length);
    CaretIndex = caretIndex;
  }
  #endregion
}
```

**Working Sample:**

**[Download Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9p73gqzwu3xlh3/CustomPasswordBox.rar)**

You can type something into the control and check the stored value shown below it.

In this sample, I've added a new DP of type `string` to just show that the control works fine. You'd obviously not want to have that DP (`HiddenText`) in your live-code, but I'd hope the sample helps to analyze if the class actually works :)

Comment: Wow, thanks Viv! That is exactly the type of thing I was looking for! Thanks for helping out a WPF newbie.

Comment: For some reason I can't Bind the ``Password``-DP. It simply never updates. Is SecureString just not bindable? I use SecureString everywhere in my application until I have to store it to a file. Then I get the string temporary and instantly encrypt it with a defined key. The same, when I read the value. So SecureString is good for this kind of design I think. But I can't update it with Bindings =/

Comment: While an upvote would normally be enough, it's not here.  This is extremely good work!  I would add Show Password as recommended by NIST.